# How to get an array where the last element is neither the previous item or the first element?

Tags: php, modulo

I have a slider with a loop (last element is followed by first element) and want to set a different color (based on a range of 3 colors).

So there is 2 conditions: previous color and next color must not be the same AND quantity of slides (elements in the array) may vary.

Good example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => yellow
    [1] => blue
    [2] => red
    [3] => yellow
    [4] => red
)
```

Bad example (because elements 0 and 4 are the same color):

```
Array
(
    [0] => yellow
    [1] => blue
    [2] => yellow
    [3] => red
    [4] => yellow
)
```

Another bad example with more elements (because elements 2 and 3 are the same color):

```
Array
(
    [0] => yellow
    [1] => blue
    [2] => red
    [3] => red
    [4] => blue
    [5] => yellow
    [6] => blue
)
```

This is what I try, but I don't think this is the good way:

```
$i = 0;
$bgcolors = array();
foreach($slides as $slide) {
    switch ($i % 3) {
        case 0:
            $bgcolors[] = 'yellow';
            break;
        case 1:
            $bgcolors[] = 'blue';
            break;
        case 2:
            $bgcolors[] = 'red';
            break;
    }

    if ((count($slides) - $i) % 3 == 0) $i = 0;

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: For first (Good) example it should be blue color right? or you need all color which is between different two color?

Comment: @HareshVidja Yes, that's right. As previous color is red and next color is yellow, blue is the only option in this case.

Comment: you need array or multiple color ot only first color which satisfy your condition?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but can't you just compare the element to the next one and see if they're the same? bgcolors[i] != bgcolors[(i+1)%bgcolors.length]

Comment: Why? Is this a "do my homework for me" question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't think this is the good way

It is a relatively elegant and efficient way to ensure that you don't have consecutive matching colours on a single pass through the results. But it could be more elegant using the method proposed by jeroen.

However it does not address the problem where the list wraps around. Obvously, with an unknown number of slides (M), there is a 1 in N chance (where N is the number of colours) that the 1st slide will be allocated the same colour as the last one. But it is simple to work out when this is the case:

```
M % N = 1
```

So as long as M%N is not one it is a problem you don't have to worry about. When M%N is 1, then you only need to worry changing the colour of *either* the first or the last slide. For the sake of argument, we'll change the colour of the last one.

So that just leaves the problem of which colour to pick.

In the absence of a change, the last slide will be the same colour as the first, and we can't change it to the colour earlier in the cycle as that will make it the same as the penultimate slide.

Joeroen's solution is rather messy - search for a colour not used in the previous or later slides and apply that. It uses more code than is necessary. You just pick the second colour in the list.

However jeroen is wrong in saying that the problem can be solved with 2 colours (or less!). No amount of code will help if only 2 colours and an odd number of slides greater than 1.

hence:

```
  $colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red'];
  if (count($slides)>count($colors) && 3>count($colors)) {
      trigger_error("unsolvable");
  }
  $i = 0;
  $bgcolors = array();
  foreach($slides as $slide) {
     $bgcolors[] = $colors[$i % count($colours)];
     $i++;
  }
  if (1 < count($slides) && 1 == count($slides) % count($colors)) {
     $bgcolors[count($slides)-1]=$colors[1];
  }
```

Comment: The last part isn't easy to understand. But seems to be the correct way.

Comment: I am definitely not saying this can be solved in all cases; additional checks are simply needed to avoid getting in a never-ending loop. But, yes, you can solve this more elegantly using simple mathematics :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should start with putting your colors in an array.

Then, at the end of the array, you need to add some logic to make sure neither the previous nor the first color is used:

```
$colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red'];
$i = 0;
$bgcolors = array();
foreach($slides as $slide) {
    $bgcolors[] = $colors[$i % 3];

    $i++;

    if ($slide == end($slides) {
        $j = $i;
        while ($bgcolors[$i - 1] === $colors[$j % 3] || $bgcolors[0] === $colors[$j % 3]) {
            $j++;
        }
        $bgcolors[] = $colors[$j % 3];
    }
}
```

Note that you need to add conditions if your color or slider array can have 2 elements or less...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming colors can be random (except for the mentioned restrictions, of course) :

```
$slides = array('slide1', 'slide2', 'slide3', 'slide4', 'slide5');
$colors = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow');
$bg_colors = array();

foreach ($slides as $key=>$value) {
    if ($key == 0) { // First slide
        $bg_colors[] = $colors[mt_rand(0, 2)]; // Get random color
    } else { // Other slides
        $usable_colors = $colors; // Duplicate colors array
        $usable_colors = array_values(array_diff($usable_colors, array($bg_colors[$key-1]))); // Remove last used color and reset keys
        if ($key == count($slides) -1) { // Last slide
            $usable_colors = array_values(array_diff($usable_colors, array($bg_colors[0]))); // Remove first used color and reset keys
        }
        $bg_colors[] = $usable_colors[mt_rand(0, count($usable_colors)-1)]; // Get random color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do this is to ask for all the possible colors different from the last one and the first one in the slider, and then pick up one at random.

```
function getColorsForElements( $numbersOfElements ) {

$colors_array   = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow');
$bg_colors  = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $numbersOfElements; $i++) {
    if  ($i == $numbersOfElements - 1 )
        $first_color    = reset($bg_colors);
    else
        $first_color = false;

    $last_color     = end($bg_colors);

    $possible_colors = array_diff($colors_array, array($first_color, $last_color) );

    $index = array_rand($possible_colors, 1);
    array_push($bg_colors, $possible_colors[$index] );
}

return $bg_colors;
}
```

An example of usage is `getColorsForElements( 5 )` which gives as result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => yellow
    [1] => blue
    [2] => red
    [3] => blue
    [4] => red
)
```

Comment: Not a clean solution - a brute force one

Comment: @symcbean why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red'];
$bgcolors = array($colors[2]);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($slides); ++$i) {
    $bgcolors[] = $colors[$i%2];
}
```

This meets your two conditions. But now you will probably tell me the third one, because it can't be as easy :-)

Answer (score -1):

As i understand your question, here is the solution

```
$i = 0;
$bgcolors = array();
foreach($slides as $slide) {
if ($i > 2) $i = 0;
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        $bgcolors[] = 'yellow';
        break;
    case 1:
        $bgcolors[] = 'blue';
        break;
    case 2:
        $bgcolors[] = 'red';
        break;
}

$i++;
}
```